# Does CPU heating to 90 C cause any permanent damage?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I have a MacBook Air 6,2 (2013) with an i7 (1.7 GHz normally). When I was installing Debian on it I completely forgot about the "Turbo Boost" feature — my CPU was clocked at its highest possible value, and consistently reaching 80-90 degrees. I've since clocked it back but I just wanted to make sure it didn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

The i7-4650u has a max operating temp of close to 100c so you were pushing it close but it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My Macbook reached 108/109° and still works great since 2008!
Steve Jobs hate fan noise so Macbook heat a lot, is normal, no damage! When it start overheating there's an alarm that freeze temporarily Mac but I've never see it!

Comment: It might be different for a MacBook Air since it's much more tightly packed (that's what I was worried about, and it may also be different with an SSD).

Comment: probably but all MacBooks heat a lot and is all under control, when it become dangerous Mac turns off. Don't worry, a short little "overheat" due to an installation can't damage your mac!